# how to estimate the phase parameter of a complex function

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

There is a complex serie: $f(t_n)=\alpha_n+\beta_n i$, for $n = 1,...,N$,$t_n,\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are known.When we have know that $f(t)$ has the following form:
$$f(t)=Ae^{-iBt}$$
with unknown amplitude $A$ and unknown phase $B$, how to estimate the parameters $A$ and $B$ by using a numerical optimization method?

Comment: Are you trying to fit data to the model ?

Comment: See http://www.fasebj.org/content/1/5/365.full.pdf.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici,yes

Comment: @Wangyan. See my answer and come back if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As written by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, let us suppose that you want to find the optimum values of parameters $A$ and $B$ which minimize the objective function $$\Phi(A,B)=\sum _{n=1}^N (\alpha_n-A\cos (Bt_n))^2+(\beta_n+A\sin (Bt_n))^2=\sum _{n=1}^N r_n$$ Now, since you want the objective function to be minimum, write its derivatives with respect to  $A$ and $B$ and set them equal to zero. This will then correspond to  $$\sum _{n=1}^N  \frac{dr_n}{dA}=0$$ $$\sum _{n=1}^N  \frac{dr_n}{dB}=0$$ This corresponds respectively to $$\sum _{n=1}^N [A-\alpha _n \cos (B t_n)+\beta_n \sin (B t_n)]=0$$ $$\sum _{n=1}^N [A t_n (\alpha_n \sin (B t_n)+\beta_n \cos (B t_n))]=0$$ What is nice is that the first equation allows to explicit $A$ as a function of $B$; so, only the second equation is left and you can solve it using Newton method provided that you have a reasonable guess (notice than $A$ disappears from the second equation).

As written by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, you could start your iterations computing the average value of the $$B_n= -\frac1{t_n}\arctan\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}$$ over the entire data set.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring answer, but I still did not get the right  $B$. Here is my procedure: as you said, I should find the zero point of $\sum_{n=1}^N {dr_n\over dA}=0$, that is $\sum_{n=1}^N {[At_n(\alpha_nsin(Bt_n)+\beta_ncos(Bt_n))]}=0$. I should cancel $A$ from the left side, because it is nonzero, then I get $$\sum_{n=1}^N {t_n(\alpha_nsin(Bt_n)+\beta_ncos(Bt_n))}=0$$ Let $$f(B)=\sum_{n=1}^N {t_n(\alpha_nsin(Bt_n)+\beta_ncos(Bt_n))}$$, its derivative with respect to B is $f'(B)=\sum_{n=1}^N {t_n^2(-\alpha_ncos(Bt_n)+\beta_nsin(Bt_n))}$. I use $B_{k+1}=B_k-f'(B_k)$ to estimate B.

Comment: Your derivative is wrong (change the sign). And you iterative scheme must be $$B_{k+1}=B_k-f(B_k) / f'(B_k)$$ PLease let me know.

Comment: Haha, it is a clerical mistake about the sign. On the other hand, $-f(B_k)/f'(B_k)$ and $-f'(B_k)$ have a same direction, but different step length. Actually, I use this $-f''^{-1}(B_k)f'(B_k)$ to be the compensation at every step. But still doesn't work.

Comment: Since you use Newton, you **must** use what I wrote. If I may suggest, plot $f(B)$ as a function of $B$ and see where it cancels. If you want, post the data or send them to me by e-mail.

Comment: I use Newton to estimate both $A$ and $B$ simultaneously, so the direction $p$ is $$-[{{\partial \Phi}\over{\partial A}}\quad{{\partial \Phi}\over{\partial B}}]'$$ and step length is $$[{{\partial^2 \Phi}\over{\partial A^2}}\quad{{\partial^2 \Phi}\over{\partial A\partial B}};{{\partial^2 \Phi}\over{\partial A\partial B}}\quad{{\partial^2 \Phi}\over{\partial B^2}}]$$

Comment: You do not take my answer into account. $A$ is a function of $B$ and there is only **one** equation to solve $f(B)=0$ using Newton. When you have $B$, compute $A$ from my first equation. Don't try to solve both equations simulaneously; you would be in trouble because the system is poorly conditioned. Cheers.

Comment: The data are generated from the function $y=20e^{-i*2\pi*200*t}$ in which $t\in [0,1]$ and $t_0=0,t_k-t_{k-1}=1/1024$

Comment: I tried your answer, but ...Can I send you my Matlab code? By the way, what do you mean the system is poorly conditioned?

Comment: do you mean it is very sensitive to tiny shifts in the data values (unstable)? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(t)=Ae^{−iBt}=A(\cos(Bt)-i\sin(Bt))$$
$$\alpha_n+\beta_n i=f(t_n)=A(\cos(Bt_n)-i\sin(Bt_n))$$
$$A=|\alpha_n+\beta_n i|=\sqrt{\alpha_n^2+\beta_n^2}$$
$$B= -\frac1{t_n}\arctan\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I mean how to estimate them by numerical optimization method, like Newton's method.

Comment: Then, try a best fit, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting, minimizing $\sum((\alpha_n-A\cos Bt_n)^2+(\beta_n+A\sin Bt_n)^2)$.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but I found that it is difficult to  estimate $B$ by using Newton's method.